# Workflow Task List missing

Tags: list, workflow, workflow-history

I am new to SharePoint workflows.  I am following along on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ym-NlQgqihg&index=37&list=PLkxSkUuLZ3fTmkn0BP8L0nPtSz3TzETl0) .

Starting at the 24min mark, she discusses The **Workflow Tasks list**.

[image]

She mentions that I have to publish a workflow for the first time to have it appear.

I created a simple workflow and published it.

Here is what I see:

[image]

*How do I get the Workflow Tasks list and Workflow History list to appear?
What settings am I missing?*

Thank you for taking a look.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it by creating a new Workflow

- From designer click on Workflows
- From ribbon click on List Workflows
- Select a list you want the workflow to be associated with
- Click Publish

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a workflow association for the list to be created.

Try publishing a workflow that is linked to a list.